# How to combine tables to create one bar plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, filter, bar-chart, dplyr

I would like to know, how I can combine my tables to create one bar plot.
I first mutated and created new columns... but the answers are TRUE OR FALSE

```
master1 <- master %>%
  mutate(underweight = BMI < 18.5,
         normal = between(BMI, 18.5, 24.9),
         overweight = between(BMI, 25, 29.9),
         obese = between(BMI, 30, 34.9),
         extreme = BMI > 35)
```

as I didn't know how to create from this table a bar plot, I splitted them in new tables:

```
t.underweight<-master1 %>%
  filter(Income>0,underweight==TRUE) %>%
  select(Income,underweight)

t.normal<-master1%>%
  filter(Income>0,normal==TRUE)%>%
  select(Income,normal)

t.overweight<-master1%>%
  filter(Income>0,overweight==TRUE)%>%
  select(Income,overweight)

t.obese<-master1%>%
  filter(Income>0,obese==TRUE)%>%
  select(Income,obese)

t.extreme<-master1%>%
  filter(Income>0,extreme==TRUE)%>%
  select(Income,extreme)
```

maybe there is an easier way to direct after mutating, if yes I would appreciate to learn how. if not how can I just combine this table to create a barplot?
my second variable would be " Income " ... on the y-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this?
[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
bmi <- runif(100, 10, 50)
income <- rnorm(100, 400, 10)
id <- 1:100

df <- data.frame(id = id, bmi = bmi, income = icnome)

res <- df %>% 
  mutate(BMI_cat = cut(
    x = bmi,
    breaks = c(0, 18.5, 25, 30, 35, Inf),
    labels = c("underweight", "normal", "overweight", "obese", "extreme"),
    ordered_result = T
  ))

ggplot(res, aes(income)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 10) +
  facet_wrap(~BMI_cat, scales = "fixed")
```

Comment: Hello Yuriy, thanks for your help ..
I am kind of searching something like this...

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Comment: Yes sure.. one more question, but how is it possible when the answers are like TRUE and FALSE? 

`t.extreme<-master1%>%
  filter(Income>0,extreme==TRUE)%>%
  select(Income,extreme)

> head(t.extreme)
  Income extreme
1  21600    TRUE
2   4000    TRUE
3  12720    TRUE
4  26772    TRUE`